# rails_admin Change belongs_to Drop-down to Display Options from Different Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, has-many, rails-admin, belongs-to

I am using `rails_admin 0.6.5` with `Rails 4.1.6` and have a `has_many` / `belongs_to` association setup between the Volume and Issue models respectively:

```
class Volume < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues, :inverse_of => :volume

  validates :number, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 1}
end
```

and the Issue model:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :volume, :inverse_of => :issues

  validates :number, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 1}
  validates :date, presence: true
end
```

Within the `rails_admin` interface, it works but when creating or editing an Issue, the Volume drop-down menu is populated with the text `Volume #1`, `Volume #2`, `Volume #3` (each as a separate option). Those "volume numbers" correspond to `:volume_id`, not the Volume's `:number` field, which is different than the ID and therefore confusing to users.

When creating or editing an Issue, how do I control which Volume column is displayed in the `belongs_to` association drop-down menu? Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 4):

Rails Admin looks for certain properties on your model for display purposes.  There is an array RailsAdmin.config.label_methods that contains these properties in order of preference.

By default they are [:name, :title]

I like to add :display_name to the front of the list so that I can easily override any models that have a name column on the db.

In order to do this, add the following line to `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
config.label_methods.unshift(:display_name)
```

Then, in your model:

```
    class Volume < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :issues, :inverse_of => :volume

      validates :number, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 1}

      def display_name
        "Volume #{self.number}"
      end

    end
```